# Split xml string at ">

Tags: xml, xslt, split

I have a simple xml file (will be much longer later on) with only one value,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cr.xsl"?>
<companyroutes>
  <route name="EKCHLOWI">SALLO UM44 KOGIM UM725 BESKO UZ36 MAREM UT106 VESUB T106 NETES T700 DEGIN UP31 DOSEL</route>
  <route name="ENGMEDDF">ENGM TOR P615 LBE N850 PIROT T152 KERAX EDDF</route>
</companyroutes>
```

I need to transform it via xslt to a table on webpage, but I need the output to be showed like:

```
**EKCHLOWI** SALLO UM44 KOGIM UM725 BESKO UZ36 MAREM UT106 VESUB T106 NETES T700 DEGIN UP31 DOSEL
```

Since the line only have one "name", how can I split the string into two tables, divided at "> ?
What will the cr.xsl look like?

The xml is used by 3rd part software, so I cannot manipulate it as it will not work if I change the format of syntax.
I cannot insert `<catalog>` to the xml file or split the data into

...I'm such a novice...

EDIT:
The html should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
      <body>
      <h2>BBL - CompanyRoutes</h2>
      <table border="1">
        <tr>
          <th>Route Name</th>
          <th>Route</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="????">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="Route Name"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="Route"/></td>
        </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
      </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

...After the example for: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp

Note that I have only ???? where I should refer to catalog in the.xml file, wich I have'nt.

Comment: I think I do not get the problem. You can get the attribute value with an xPath like this: `/route@name` and the value of the text node you can get with this xPath `/route/text()`. If you then made a `<xsl:for-each select='//route'>` loop and retrieve the values with the xPath `@name` and `text()`, you should have everything you need.

Comment: Would it be possible to show the actual HTML code you wish to output? At the moment, you mention a 'table' but it looks like you just wish to output it as a single string. Also, are you able to use XSLT 2.0, or just XSLT 1.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your updated question:

Your for each loop should select each route element. Like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//route">
```

And the correct xPaths for the route name and the route should be like this:

```
<tr>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="./@name"/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="./text()"/></td>
</tr>
```

This of course assumes you have an input like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<companyroutes>
  <route name="EKCHLOWI">SALLO UM44 KOGIM UM725 BESKO UZ36 MAREM UT106 VESUB T106 NETES T700 DEGIN UP31 DOSEL</route>
  <route name="ENGMEDDF">ENGM TOR P615 LBE N850 PIROT T152 KERAX EDDF</route>
</companyroutes>
```

Comment: Thats great. Getting the start in a new lib/technique is always the hardest part. If your problem is solved, please do not forget to accept an answer (tick the green checkmark) so others do bother to answer an already solved problem anymore.